# how to copy data from existing to another same structured table in HANA

Tags: hana

I tried to insert data to a new table from an existing table in HANA and I used

```
INSERT INTO "SCHEMA"."NEW_TABLE" SELECT * FROM   "SCHEMA"."OLD_TABLE"
```

the query was executing but in the end it showed lost data connectivity. Now I cannot login to the HANA as the USER which I was using. Was my query wrong? Could anyone clarify me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your login issues have nothing to do with your INSERT command.
If the system is still reachable e.g. with a admin user you may want to check the indexserver trace files to find out the reason for the connection loss.